# jQuery draggable and sortable not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

The setup has a few issues which I'm trying to solve, been at it for a while now. Basically, I've made it sortable so you can move items to another folder. But as you might not have every folder open (not shown in jsfiddle) it is setup to use a hover class, but when dragging a file and it starts sorting, the hover class still sometimes shows even though I'm not hovering over a folder...

Also after sorting a file, trying to drag it around again makes it glitch up and makes it so you cant really move it again for some reason.

https://jsfiddle.net/4Lz5Lfsj/12/

HTML:

```
<main>
  <div id="menu">
    <ul id="menuul">
      <li class="folder">Folder</li>
      <li class="folder">Folder</li>
      <li class="folder">Folder</li>
      <ul>
        <li class="clippet">File</li>
        <li class="clippet">File</li>
      </ul>

      <li class="clippet">File</li>
      <li class="clippet">File</li>
      <li class="clippet">File</li>
      <li class="clippet">File</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
main
{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-right: 12px;
}

#menu ul li
{
  display: flex;
}

#menu ul li p
{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.draggableHover
{
  background-color: grey;
}
```

JS:

```
$(".clippet").draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    scroll: false,
    delay: 300,
    cursorAt: { left: -5 },
    cursor: 'move',
    connectToSortable: '#menuul'
  });

  $(".folder").droppable({
    accept: ".clippet",
    hoverClass: 'draggableHover'
  });

  $("#menuul").sortable(
  {
    revert: true,
    handle: 'p'
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by changing the class to those folders are not allowed to drop files, to emulate sub-levels within of folders as your code, every folder should have own ul and append the file when this is dropped into the folder.

`over` and `out` function could help you to highlight the folder which are allowed to drop files.

Here the idea working:

https://jsfiddle.net/4Lz5Lfsj/17

Comment: Yes but what about when you drag them in between folders, sometimes the red will stay shown, even though you are not directly hovering on the folder, if you get me? And after you place a sortable file, then go to drag it again it still does not allow you to drag it around past the parent, as it did before when you first load the page?

Comment: @Erdss4 the `ul` inside of `ul.menuu1` is to emulate the files inside of that folder?

Comment: Yes each inner ul is to emulate inside of a folder. I wanted to be able to move a file and use .sortable() to make it possible to move a file in between a folder and when dropped would put it back at root level, but sometimes when you move the file between folders, the hover class stays on even though you are not directly over a folder, if that makes sense?

Comment: @Erdss4 here an idea to highlight the folder with `over`,`out` and `drop` functions. work in a better way https://jsfiddle.net/4Lz5Lfsj/15/

Comment: @Erdss4 emulating the idea of folders inside a folder, here a workaround how can you achieve this. https://jsfiddle.net/4Lz5Lfsj/17/